# After updating MacOS to 10.14.6 webdriverIO keys function does not work locally

Tags: macos, selenium, webdriver-io

I moved the work from Windows to a Macbook running MacOS. I imported the entire development environment and it worked properly for some time. But on Friday, after the macOS update, it stopped working (I think that was the reason).

When I try to run a cucumber test with JS, I get an error in the step where I want to press the Enter key.

> POST /session/hereis sesion id/actions Build info: version: '3.141.0',
>   revision: '2ecb7d9a', time: '2018-10-31T20:22:52' System info: host:
>   'Administrators-MacBook-Pro.local', ip: 'IP number', os.name: 'Mac OS
>   X', os.arch: 'x86_64', os.version: '10.14.6', java.version: '12.0.2'
>   Driver info: driver.version: unknown running chrome Error: The
>   requested resource could not be found, or a request was received using
>   an HTTP method that is not supported by the mapped resource.
>       at actions([object Object]) - keys.js:94:2

Line 94 in keys.js it this one with version in os

```
 interface Status {
        build?: {
            version: string;
            revision?: string;
            time?: string;
        };

        os?: {
            name: string;
            arch?: string;
            version?: string;
        };

        java?: {
            version?: string;
        };
    }
```

On Windows with same version of chrome-drivers and selenium standalone server, this code works.